# Python ctypes dll load error 487

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, dll, ctypes

I am using Python 2.7 and trying to load a dll with ctypes:

> lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("mylib.dll")

It sometimes throws the following error, some other times it runs ok. Also with Python 3 always throws this error:

> libcrypto = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("data\openvpn\libeay32")   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
>       return self._dlltype(name)   File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 362, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) WindowsError: [Error 487] Attempt to access invalid address

Comment: are both dll and python 32 (64) bit? Have you also tried  ctypes.CDLL("data\openvpn\libeay32") ?

Comment: Yes both dll and python are on 32bit. Yes tried, the same behavior.

Comment: That's not normal.  It sounds like a problem with the DLL itself, which without source we cannot attempt to fix.

Comment: Do you have any idea what this error means exactly ? Like what kind of code may cause this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were having a similar issue with a FIPS-certified version of OpenSSL.  Unfortunately, that version of OpenSSL is required to be loaded at a specific memory address.  If you try to load OpenSSL too late when starting an application, the memory address it requires has already been taken by another dependency.  The best we could figure out to "fix" this is to ensure OpenSSL (libeay32.dll) is loaded into the memory address space as soon as possible.

In your case, add the following lines **AT THE TOP** of your Python script (NOTE: *AT THE TOP* means before any other line of executable code, including import statements):

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes.util import find_library
cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library('libeay32'))
```

Alternatively, you could ensure that *libeay32.dll* is the first dependency listed within *mylib.dll*.

**BEGIN EDIT**

While the above code helped increase the probability of success in my case, it still loaded the OpenSSL DLL too late in some instances.  To fix this, I had to create a new Python wrapper executable in C++, with the following code:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "openssl\crypto.h"

auto volatile GetVersionOpenSSL{ &SSLeay };

int wmain(size_t const argc, wchar_t const *const argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    int const result{ Py_Main(argc, const_cast<wchar_t**>(argv)) };
    Py_Finalize();
    return result;
}
```

Note that I had to take the following additional actions as well:

1. Add *libeay32.lib* as the first library in the linker command line
2. Disable the linker optimization to remove unused references

Call the resulting executable instead of python.exe with the same arguments, and that error should go away.